# LED blinking array using LC-circuit

Tags: led, transformer, ac-dc, blink

Basically I want to create a blinking unit to drive my LED's. The LED's are used to be driven at a frequency of ~1.5Hz (that made me choose the values of L and C).

So here is my schematic. (I am physicist so there might be some issues with current direction...)

(The PNP is used to block the supply-current if the capacitor is charged.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsfd0h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

After a while of thinking about it I got to the point that this wont work because the resistance in the LC-circuit will cause that there wont be any oscillation. Even if in D3 is only a single LED...

And now I have no idea how to get my 12V DC current into a 12V AC current with a frequency of 1.5Hz. I searched a long time how to do this but I don't get it how to get it working.

I found i.e. circuits of power inverters but all of them (I found) are at 50Hz and 230V AC output.

How could I get it working to transform my 12V DC to 12V AC (f=1.5Hz) without using an IC. Well I thought of using a quartz but no one I found has a sufficient low frequency...

Comment: 500H is a **VERY** large inductor. Is there some reason why you don't want to use an IC and want to use LC as opposed to RC?

Comment: I know it is very large, that is from some easy calculation. I already decided that I am going to change that. Well i might us an IC as long as I dont need to program it and it is more more efficient than not using one.

Comment: Okay, the science of blinky-LEDs is fairly advanced. Someone should be along with a 555 circuit momentarily, as well as a suggestion on using avalanching BJTs or a PIC.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yep, I'm looking for a good 555 image :)

Comment: Haha that'll be me.

Comment: Hmm... 500 Henries... You'd need a very large, permeable core. Perhaps made out of mu metal. All the mu metal. Everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a 555 timer chip. No programming necessary and there are a gazillion circuit ideas on the net. Google "astable oscillator". It should be able to directly drive a LED directly but if you need more power use a mosfet amplifier.

**EDIT to show a calculator for the 555**

[This](http://freespace.virgin.net/matt.waite/resource/handy/pinouts/555/) website has calculators for various 555 timer circuits. Here's a picture: -

[image]

Note the values of R1, R2 and C - these give a frequency of basically 1.5Hz and a duty cycle of about 51%. This is how easy it is but take note that power supply voltage variations will "tweak" the results slightly.

[Here's](http://www.ohmslawcalculator.com/555_astable.php) another one: -

[image]

Comment: Well, @AndyAka beat me to it, but here is a [tutorial](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_oscillator.html) on exactly what you are looking for :)

Comment: So if I would take this one: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Astable_multivibrator.png
The 555 timer chip is? I just see two NPN's.

Comment: You could use that but I'd recommend using a 555 astable multivibrator

Comment: For my use I calculated the following: a) R_1=20 Ohm, R_2=470 Ohm and C=1 µF or b) R_1=20 kOhm, R_2=470 kOhm and C=1 mF.  Which one would be the better choice? And what kind of capacitor should I use?

Comment: dunno pls show a circuit

Comment: Values meant to be taken with this circuit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:555_Monostable.svg  and a supplying voltage of 12V.

Comment: No, that's a monostable or one-shot. "ASTABLE" is the key word. Also try googling try calculator. I'm on android phone so it's difficult to make a link for you.

Comment: @maximus_de - see the pictures I've added and the links

Comment: Oh, that was the wrong link. It was meant to be this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:555_Astable_Diagram.svg.  And the values on the upper comment seem to be gone messed up... thanks for the links they helped a lot.

Comment: @Andyaka: That second 555 calculator screengrab has to be disregarded. It's in [Comic Sans](http://www.comicsanscriminal.com/).

Comment: @transistor I'm not sure what you are getting at - is the 2nd calculator screenshot disreputable? Is comic sans some kind of site that shows bad sites. I genuinely haven't come across this before.

Comment: Sorry to cause confusion with an attempt at humour. There are several sites that highlight inappropriate (over)use of Comic Sans which was the only informal font shipped with MS Windows. The website is fine. ;^)

Comment: @transistor that's OK then - thought I might have to start deleting pictures.

Comment: Is misinterpreting Comic Sans when calling out Comic Sans the new "grammar mistake in the grammar complaint"? (That isn't Comic Sans, but rather some other cursive style typeface. That being said, I rather like it.)

Answer (score 0):

Using 1uF capacitor and a few MOhm feedback will get you a square wave.  Symmetry is skewed if R is too high compared to capacitor leakage R or too low R as in below example compared to old CMOS drive impedance.[image]
 CMOS can drive small LEDs.